# Profile a C# application running on RDP

Tags: c#, winforms, profiling, rdp

I have a application that is running slow only over RDP.

This is what I know by now:

- It is the InitializeComponents() method that is slow
- App is only slow when RDPs "Use local printers" is enabled.

What I dont know:

- If it is one statement in the InitializeComponents() method that is slow, or several.

Idealy I would want to retrieve a list over all statements in the method sorted by the one that uses the most time. Ideally I dont want to install any software on the customers server.

Any thoughs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach to proccess using [Visual Studion remote debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx) or you can use [JetBrains dotTrace remote profiler feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/webhelp/Profiling_Guidelines__Remote_Computer.html). Both of this method will require you to run "agent" on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to inspect what are you doing in `InitializeComponents`. Especially parts when you are creating not-standard windows forms components.

Of course you can use some profiler (for example look at Orsol answer), but probably it will be faster if you add your own code inside `InitializeComponents` to find out which part is slowing you down.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree with you and Orsol. I'm probably going to have to do profiling to solve this. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @AndersLindas you do not need to thanks on StackOverflow. Voting up useful or marking as answer is enough.